# Is there a way to make setTimeout() return a value with async callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, settimeout

I have an async function that makes an API call. It is passed to my setTimeout() in this form:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.pollingId = setTimeout(this.someOtherFunc, 2000)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(this.pollingId)// clears an old polling id initialised in previous polling call
}

someOtherFunc = async () => {
  await axios.get('/some/api')

  clearTimeout(this.pollingId)
  if (someConditionToContinuePolling) {
     this.pollingId = setTimeout(this.someOtherFunc, 2000) // this will not return a value and update this.pollingId before reloadFunc is over
  }
}
```

So in case the API request takes longer, when I navigate to other page while the request is still being processed, componentWillUnmount clears an old pollingId, leaving the other one not cleared up.
Is there a way to make setTimeout not wait for the async callback to be finished to return its id?

**UPDATE**:
I don't mind the current request to finish, my issue is that if I navigate to another page while the request is being processed, componentWillUnmount clears the previous `pollingId`, and this.someOtherFunc() keeps calling itself through setTimeout() and never stops polling

Comment: The assignment to `pollingId` happens immediately, it doesn't wait for the timeout to trigger. What's probably happening is you have queued two `setTimeouts` but overwritten the `pollingId` to the latest. Instead, if you'll have overlapping timeouts, you'll need to store an array of `pollingId`s, or before starting another clear any existing.

Comment: But if you mean you want to stop any running `reloadFunc` calls then clearing the timeout is not sufficient to cancel the running async operations. Instead you'll need to abort them explicitly. See: [Abort Controller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)

Comment: @pilchard sorry, I didn't include the part where I do clear the current pollingId, so I don't think there's an overlapping issue. I realise I didn't include the exact logic of my current implementation, I have updated my question it to be more accurate.

Comment: @DashaRee could you see, please, my reply and check whether it is eligible for you?

Comment: @pilchard you were totally correct about aborting current function call. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

As  mdn says about [return value of setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#return_value):

> The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies
> the timer created by the call to setTimeout(). This value can be
> passed to `clearTimeout()` to cancel the timeout.

So you can collect all `timeoutID's`, put them in an array and run `clearTimeout` with these Ids. Let's create array that will store all timeoutID's and code would look like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.pollingId = setTimeout(this.reloadFunc, 2000)
  this.addIdTimeoutIds(this.pollingId)
}

someOtherFunc = () => {
  this.pollingId = setTimeout(this.reloadFunc, 2000) 
  this.addIdTimeoutIds(this.pollingId)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.timeoutIDs.forEach(timeoutId => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
}

addIdTimeoutIds = (pollingId) =>
    this.timeoutIDs.push(pollingId)
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to abort your request, you can use AbortController (special thanks to [Pilchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard)).

This is an example of [using with Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#abortcontroller):

```
const controller = new AbortController();

axios.get('/foo/bar', {
   signal: controller.signal
}).then(function(response) {
   //...
});
// cancel the request
controller.abort()
```

Comment: This is part of the problem, as noted in my comment, but I think the larger problem the OP is facing is aborting already running `reloadFunc` calls.

Comment: @pilchard thanks! :) I've updated my reply. Please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I realized the root problem was not connected to clearing correct `pollingId`. It was about aborting the new initiation of setTimeout calls inside this.someOtherFunc(). Since setTimeout() is calling the function it is inside of, I had a situation of the current callback calling and initiating new setTimeOut again inside of it.

@pilchard 's answer about aborting the already running function call has pushed me towards this solution. Thank you very much!

Just adding a flag to stop polling worked.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.pollingId = setTimeout(this.someOtherFunc, 2000)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearTimeout(this.pollingId)// clears an old polling id initialised in previous polling call
  this.stopPolling = true
}

someOtherFunc = async () => {
  await axios.get('/some/api')

  clearTimeout(this.pollingId)
  if (someConditionToContinuePolling && !stopPolling) {
     this.pollingId = setTimeout(this.someOtherFunc, 2000) // this will not return a value and update this.pollingId before reloadFunc is over
  }
}
```